# Flutter + Android: How to remove firebase from project "E/FirebaseInstanceId: Failed to resolve target intent service"

Tags: android, firebase, flutter

I used Firebase in an old iteration of my flutter project, but I guess I either didn't remove it properly or it was there all the time.  In any case, how do i get rid of Firebase and hence forth remove this error from my Android logs?  I've grepped the entire project and cannot find 1 instance of firebase.  I've removed it from my yaml file a while back and still this pops up.

> FirebaseInstanceId: Failed to resolve target intent service, skipping
>   classname enforcement FirebaseInstanceId: Error while delivering the
>   message: ServiceIntent not found.

Here's my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.eumag">
    <!-- The INTERNET permission is required for development. Specifically,
         flutter needs it to communicate with the running application
         to allow setting breakpoints, to provide hot reload, etc.
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />

    <!-- io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication is an android.app.Application that
         calls FlutterMain.startInitialization(this); in its onCreate method.
         In most cases you can leave this as-is, but you if you want to provide
         additional functionality it is fine to subclass or reimplement
         FlutterApplication and put your custom class here.
         android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"

         -->

    <application
        android:name=".ServiceChannel"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:label="eumag">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- This keeps the window background of the activity showing
                 until Flutter renders its first frame. It can be removed if
                 there is no splash screen (such as the default splash screen
                 defined in @style/LaunchTheme). -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.app.android.SplashScreenUntilFirstFrame"
                android:value="true" />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "http://www.example.com/gizmos” -->
                <data
                    android:host="www.example.com"
                    android:pathPrefix="/eumag"
                    android:scheme="http" />
                <!-- note that the leading "/" is required for pathPrefix-->
                <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "example://gizmos” -->
                <data
                    android:host="eumag"
                    android:scheme="example" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.spotify.sdk.android.authentication.LoginActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
        <service
            android:name=".ForegroundService"
            android:stopWithTask="false">
        </service>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

My gradle file for my app

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.eumag"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation project(':spotify-app-remote')
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-compat:'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
    implementation "com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5"
//    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.9.8'
//    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.9.8'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.9.8'
    implementation 'com.spotify.android:auth:1.1.0'
    implementation ('io.socket:socket.io-client:1.0.0') {
        // excluding org.json which is provided by Android
        exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
    }
}
```

and my project gradle file

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }

    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 4):

1. Go to your pubscpec and remove all Firebase packages
2. Go to your Gradle files, root and app level and remove the Firebase references
3. Go to the root of Flutter project, delete the build folder
4. Go to your Android project remove it's build folder
5. Search for FirebaseInstanceId in your entire project (If you're using Visual studio code).

The Flutter Firebase package generates the FirebaseInstanceId and receiver when you build your project. Unless you added your own one, in that case. Just go and remove that file.

Comment: 1. Done, 
2. Done (used visual studio in-built grep: firebaseinstanceid, firebase, fire), 
3. Done, 
4. can't find it, 
5. Done (same as number 2).  But still there :(

Comment: @JohnnyBoy aah man that's a bummer. You probably have tried to uninstall the app already. The only other thing I can think of is removing all references to firebase from the AndroidManifest.xml as well. And then maybe changing your package identifier just so it's installed in a different(clean) location on the device. So remove the app, remove any references from AndroidManifest, change the package id, remove the build folder from root and run the app again.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is a solution worth trying;

**Delete android and ios folders**

Open terminal and type these commands:

```
Flutter create android
Flutter create ios
```

Or

```
Flutter create .
```

I hope this can be a solution

Answer (score 0):

You can copy your lib dir to new project without firebase

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).